# Iterating over my list does not return value i was wating for

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm reading trough a CSV and storing one of the values into a list.
When I try to compare values, it turns out that the list iterate over one item. If I print the list, I can see the full contents o the list. However if I print after a for loop  (`for i in list:`) I only get the first item  how many times there is items in the list, but always the same value.

```
def getMail(fname, lname):
    firstname = fname.split()
    lastname = lname.split()

    email = firstname[0].strip() + '.' + lastname[0].strip() + '@test.com'
    e_mails=[]

    with open('test-input.txt','r') as AD:
        rows = csv.DictReader(AD)

        for ad in rows:
            e_mails.append(ad['UserLogonName'])




    for i in e_mails:
        print(f'{i} and {email}')

         '''
             This is what i get when I print i and email. i expecxted i to be 
             an item on the list is stored.
             carlos.jimenez@test.com and Apolinar.Vargas-Morales@test.com
             carlos.jimenez@test.com and Antonio.Ochoa@test.com
             carlos.jimenez@test.com and Steven.Diaz@test.com
             carlos.jimenez@test.com and Jorge.Medrano@test.com
             carlos.jimenez@test.com and Daniel.Cerano@test.com
         '''


        print(e_mails)
        '''
           this is the content of my list from CSV
           ['carlos.jimenez@test.com', 'Carri.Dix@test.com', 'Alena.Azizi@test.com', 'Berna.Lagonaso@test.com', 'Christophe.deCarbonnieres@test.com', 'daniel.min@test.com', 'David.Li@test.com', 'John.Mitchell@test.com', 'Naveen.Sisodia@test.com', 'nadia.shakir@test.com', 'Sumeet.Sharma@smurfitkappa.com', 'benedicte.bar@test.com', 'Patricia.Aguirre@test.com']
        '''

        if email.lower() == i.lower():
            # print(f'{i} and {email}')

            print(len(firstname))

            if firstname ==2:
                email = firstname[0]+'.'+firstname[0][0:1]+'.'+lastname[0]+'@test.com'
                return email.lower()

            elif firstname ==1 :

                email = firstname[0]+'.'+firstname[0][0:1]+'.'+lastname[0]+'@test.com'
                return email.lower()
        else: 
            return email.lower() 




with open('users.csv') as csv_file:
    rows = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('users-COI2-Multi.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
        header = ['FirstName','Initials','LastName','DisplayName','Description','Office','TelePhone','UserLogonName','SamAccountName','JobTitle','Department','Manager','Mobile','faxNumber','Notes','Assistant','employeeID','ex1','ex2','ex3','ex15','Office365License','ExpiresInDays','EmailToUSer','AddToGroup']

        output_file = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=header, delimiter=';')
        output_file.writeheader()

        for data in rows:
            employeeId = data['Associate ID']
            fName = data['First Name']
            lName = data['Last Name']
            Location = data['Location']
            Department = data['Department']
            Manager = data['Manager Name']
            JobTitle = data['Title']

            context = {
                'FirstName' : fName,
                'Initials' : getInitials(fName, lName),
                'LastName' : lName,
                'DisplayName' : getDisplayName(fName, lName),
                'Description' : 'LMS Account for: '+getDisplayName(fName, lName),
                'Office': getOffice(Location).strip(),
                'TelePhone' : '+1 XXX XXX XXX',
                'UserLogonName' : getMail(fName, lName),
                'SamAccountName' : getSamA(fName, lName),
                'JobTitle' : JobTitle,
                'Department' : Department,
                'Manager' : Manager,
                'Mobile' : '',
                'faxNumber' : '',
                'Notes' : '',
                'Assistant' : '',
                'employeeID' : employeeId,
                'ex1' : 'End User',
                'ex2' : 'NoMailbox',
                'ex3' : getSiteCode(Location),
                'ex15' : getSKID(Location),
                'Office365License' : '',
                'ExpiresInDays' : '',
                'EmailToUSer' : 'victor.u.reyes@test.com',
                'AddToGroup' : '',
            }
            output_file.writerow(context)
```

Comment: @ThomasWeller  I do got an other loop in my code is how i generate my output CSV

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this return statement:

```
return email.lower()
```

at the end of the `getmail()` function. It will apply in 99% of the cases (whenever `if email.lower() == i.lower():` is not `True`), ending your search too soon.

I don't understand the exact business rules of the application you're about to develop, but my guess is that the function should be

```
def getMail(fname, lname):
    [...]

    for i in e_mails:
        [...]

        if email.lower() == i.lower():
            [...]
                               # removed else here
     return email.lower()      # outdent here
```

Another option would be

```
        elif firstname ==1 :

            email = firstname[0]+'.'+firstname[0][0:1]+'.'+lastname[0]+'@test.com'
            return email.lower()
        else:                      # indent here
            return email.lower()   # indent here
```

Also note: the two cases `if firstname ==2:` and `if firstname ==1:` look identical to me. I guess that's not intended.

Comment: So I'm trying to validate the  email I built  vs a list of emails from a CSV file.   I still have to  work on the  classification logic  after the ` for i in e_mails:`  the logic is  if an email is in the list  ad  the first letter of the first name in the middle, if users has 2 names  place sthe first letter of the second name in the middle example( victor.reyes@test.com already exist create victor.v.reyes@test.com). but i cant get in to that logic because of my for cycle returning the same item on my list ... since is not true it goes to the return all unchecked emails

Comment: Then the `firstname == 1` part is broken. You're also adding `.v` if Victor has only one name.

Comment: Yeah  i still need to work on that. the problem  is my code is not getting in to that part for testing  since i keep getting the same email

Comment: Ok. Uhm, did you read my answer? I have 2 potential solutions for you.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you , now i got to get the check right